# GCC on mac without Xcode

Tags: macos, gcc

How can I use gcc on mac (without Xcode) for C programming? Which file shall I download? How do I install and run it?

Comment: Xcode and GCC are not really related.

Comment: When you install the developer tools, you get Xcode, clang and an outdated version of gcc. Since clang is largely compatible with gcc, you should probably use it.

Comment: The easiest way is just to install Xcode - this doesn't force you to use the Xcode GUI if you don't want to - you can still do all the old skool stuff with emacs, vi, makefiles, gcc, gdb, etc.

Comment: Frankly what's wrong with this question to have 3 downvotes in 2 minutes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to [Apple dev download site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) and get the Command Line Tools. It has gcc without XCode.

Comment: Won't he need to be a registered Apple Developer to do that?

Comment: No just have an Apple ID.

Comment: thank´s CharlesB. I did it, but I also don´t know how I can run it from terminal? ;). Is" > gcc test.c -o ./test " corret to start test.c with gcc ?  sorry I´m a beginner ;)

Comment: yes it is correct. read the various tutorials to learn how to use gcc, and come back here if you have questions